# What is the swift equivalent of getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;?

Tags: android, ios

I need the density in ios so i can use it in a forumla to get the duration of an animation in ios i used it on android and it worker but i cant find it in ios
The formula

```
 getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you want the scale, result will be 1.0, 2.0, or 3.0.

Objective-C:
`CGFloat screenScale = [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale];`

Swift:
`let screenScale = UIScreen.mainScreen().scale`

Comment: I thought the scale only affected images